# Como sumar mas de un elemento de un array bidimensional y actualizar un elemento con esa suma

Tags: php, laravel, array-bidimensional

codigo usado para generar el array, actualmente este array se forma de otro para sumar las cantidades, pero no logro hacer que las cantidades que se suman se sumen entre ellas y esa suma se pongo en sumaFinal (dentro del mismo foreach, claro si es posible). He logrado que solo me sume la posicion inicial, pero las demas ya no

con este codigo genero el array

```
 $productoCantidades = array();
        foreach ($productos as $array) {
            $ids = array_column($productoCantidades, 'id');
            $pvs = array_column($productoCantidades, 'pv');
            if (FALSE !== ($k = array_search($array['pv'], $pvs))) {
                $productoCantidades[$k]['cantidad'] += $array['cantidad'];
            } else {
                if (FALSE !== ($k = array_search($array['id'], $ids))) {
                    $productoCantidades[$k]['total'] += $array['total'];
                    $productoCantidades[$k]['cantidad'] += $array['cantidad'];
                    $productoCantidades[$k]['iva'] += $array['iva'];
                    $productoCantidades[$k]['ieps'] += $array['ieps'];
                } else {
                    $productoCantidades[] = $array;
                }
            }
        }
```

el resultado da este

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "pv" => 1
    "id" => 1
    "nombre" => "Herencia Rosado Botella"
    "cantidad" => 3.0
    "total" => 540.0
    "iva" => 46.65
    "ieps" => 43.2
    "sumaFinal" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "pv" => 3
    "id" => 2
    "nombre" => "Herencia Blanco Botella"
    "cantidad" => 1.0
    "total" => "100.000"
    "iva" => "8.640"
    "ieps" => "8.000"
    "sumaFinal" => 0
  ]
]
```

pero lo que busco de resultado es esto

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "pv" => 1
    "id" => 1
    "nombre" => "Herencia Rosado Botella"
    "cantidad" => 3.0
    "total" => 540.0
    "iva" => 46.65
    "ieps" => 43.2
    "sumaFinal" => 629.85
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "pv" => 3
    "id" => 2
    "nombre" => "Herencia Blanco Botella"
    "cantidad" => 1.0
    "total" => "100.000"
    "iva" => "8.640"
    "ieps" => "8.000"
    "sumaFinal" => 116.64
  ]
]
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende.  Pues explicar un poco mas ?

Comment: era algo confuso pero ya lo logre hacer, gracias